# Installing Windows10 and Ubuntu on UEFI with GPT

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I just preparing all for install Windows and Ubuntu together in one SSD.
My plan is:
- Install Windows10 in UEFI using GPT partitions
- Install Ubuntu in UEFI using GTP (mount /boot/efi)

Now, I have the few questions about this. What will happen after install ubuntu like this. If grub-efi will detect Windows without any problems? 
How is it look like?

Comment: As long as you install Ubuntu second, there should be no problems.

Comment: In theory, it ***SHOULD*** work without problems. In practice, a combination of buggy EFIs, bugs in Ubuntu, bad documentation, and user error end up creating numerous problem reports. See [my page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) and [the Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) for documentation that can help you avoid the most common pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the installion as efi and the under windows normaly hidden boot patrtion mounted as /boot. Grub will add a extra entry for windows in grub.cfg in /boot/grub  .

you shold see a list like below afterinstallion:

Ubuntu 15.10
Windows
Ubuntu 15.10 (failsafe)
Memtest